# Providing upcasting in java explicitly

Tags: java

```
class P {
    void a() {
        System.out.println("a");
    }
    void b() {
        System.out.println("b");
    }
}

class C extends P {
    void c() {
        System.out.println("c");
    }
}

class run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
        P p =(C) c; // or  P p =(P) c; 
        p.a();
    }
}
```

In the above code I am trying to provide explicit casting, but I don't know which one is correct.

Either this:

```
P p = (C) c;
```

or this:

```
P p = (P) c;
```

Both compile and run fine.

Comment: `P p = (P) c;` because you're casting `c` to `P`

Comment: So what does another one do?

Comment: it implicitly casts c to C (which is useless), and then automatically casts C to P because P is parent

Comment: Note that if you cast a P reference to C when the actual object in the P reference is not a C (or some subclass of C) then you will get a runtime error.

Comment: @HotLicks i ddidn't get,can post just the error code line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
P p = c;
```

Don't cast at all. A `C` is a `P`; no explicit conversion is required. With no cast, you make it clear that this operation cannot fail; with a cast, you force the reader to consider and discard the possibility that `c` is not an instance of `P`.